# How can I convert an list of object to an array of list of object with each array index having 2 count?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, object

I hope everyone is doing well in this crisis.

Alright, so here is my list of objects with the object containing a name and value:

[image]

What I like to do with this list of the object is that I need to have it convert to an in
an array of list of an object with a count of array of each index of 2. e.g

When we divide the total count of list by 2 then it is 8. 
so My array will have 4 indexes with the list containing the object. But on each index of the array, the count of the list will be 2 per index.

Considering the above example for the first index:

```
Array[1 first index (rest will be same)] => List[Count = 2 of object] => {object containg the name and value}
```

What I have tried so far is by separating the key and value and looping through the count of 2 with inner loop and some other methods but can't seem to make it work for what I need. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `var myArray = new List<AdditionalPropertyJsonModel>[list.Count / 2];`

Comment: Hi @RufusL so I tried the above code you mentioned. It is dividing the list to what I want to an array but the lists in the array are null.

Comment: Yes, you need to populate it from the list

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for the help. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code that should get you started, but you'd need to validate that the initial list has an even count:

```
// This is a representation your current list, the actual one is slightly different
var list = new List<AdditionalPropertyJsonModel>
{
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "one", value = "two"},
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "three", value = "four"},
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "five", value = "six"},
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "seven", value = "eight"},
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "nine", value = "ten"},
    new AdditionalPropertyJsonModel {name = "eleven", value = "twelve"},
};

// Create an array that's half the size of the list
var myArray = new List<AdditionalPropertyJsonModel>[list.Count / 2];

// Populate the array so that each item is a list of two items from the original list
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i ++)
{
    myArray[i] = new List<AdditionalPropertyJsonModel>
    {
        // Since each index of the array represents two items from the list, we
        // multiply the array index by 2 on each iteration to get the list indexes
        // of the values we want to add to this two-item list for the array index
        list[i * 2],
        list[i * 2 + 1]
    };
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked as I wanted it to. Don't know why I didn't think of this :P.